# Context pattern? Why does Core Data need it?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm still fairly new to Core Data and am trying to understand why it requires the passing around of a NSManagedObjectContext. As I understand it, passing the context is needed so that multiple threads don't affect the same context, but I was also under the impression that this pattern is sometimes considered an antipattern, as noted [here](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/10/27/pass-around-ginormous-context-objects/).

Could Core Data theoretically be implemented in a thread safe way that would avoid using this pattern? How do other ORMs (such as Ruby's ActiveRecord for example) avoid this pattern? For example, couldn't CoreData implement a per-NSManagedObject saving method such as in this [extension](http://bikepress.tumblr.com/post/3948003272/simplifying-core-data-part-i). This light framework doesn't handle multithreading, but couldn't NSManagedObjects use some kind of internal GCD queue(s) to support it, with an internal context they don't expose?

Sorry if I'm missing anything major.

Comment: +1 for good question. I know that a big context is often seen as an anti-pattern but it does not seem to me that Apple is abusing it ina a way as say a junior programmer passing the roof shingles just to plunge the bathroom toilet. `NSManagedObjectContext` does manage a lot of things but through methods and does not require your all your entities to be available at once or for 2 entities sharing the same model to know about each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NSManagedObjectContext is the in-memory container of your applications object graph, just as the persistent store (XML, SQLite, etc.) usually represents the on disk container of your object graph.

There are some advantages to this approach:

1. Faulting can be applied to a set of objects, or in the case of CoreData the entire object graph
2. It's a convenient abstraction for forcing the application to batch it's I/O.
3. It provides a single point of contact for efficiently performing operations over the entire  object graph (NSFetchRequests, etc.)
4. Undo can be applied to the object graph, not just individual objects.

It's also important to remember that CoreData is not an ORM framework, it's an object persistence framework. The primary responsibility of CoreData is to make accessing data stored in a persistent format on disk more efficient. However it doesn't attempt to emulate the functionality of relational databases.

To your point about concurrency, new concurrency models have been introduced in the upcoming release of Mac OSX. You can read more about that at developer.apple.com.

In the abstract though, the concurrency model chosen for a managed object context has more to do with the specifics of an individual application than the context pattern itself. Instances of NSManagedObjectContext should generally never be shared between threads.

In the same way that each thread requires it's own instance of NSAutoReleasePool, each thread should also have it's own MOC. That way, when the thread is done executing, it can commit it's changes to the store on disk and then release the context, freeing up all the memory consumed by objects processed on the thread.

This is a much more efficient paradigm than allowing a single context to continuously consume system resources during the lifecycle of a given application. Of course, this can be done by invoking -reset on the context as well, which will cause all of the NSManagedObject's in use by the context to be turned back in to faults.

Answer (score 0):

You need one NSManagedObjectContext per thread. So you would have one to fill your UI on the main thread and for longer operations you would have another for each background thread. If you want results to be merged in from those other threads then there is a notification you can subscribe to that provides something to quickly merge what was changed into your main MOC.

Comment: Would there be an advantage to doing this merge yourself versus (if CoreData provided it) setting a type of merge policy and having it merge internally created objects by itself? It seems that if it could do this, it would make the API for using it much simpler.